# How to Get Item for CS GO from Steam

Tags: steam-web-api

I just try this API to get item from market steam of CS GO ==>

```
$json_strings = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamEconomy/GetAssetClassInfo/v0001?key={$config['api_key']}&format=json&language=en&appid=730&class_count=3&classid0=".$id );
                    $parsed_jsons = json_decode($json_strings);
```

But I only get of case key.

Please help me to get this all item:
http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730 using api.

i'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: That url you have in the code, does it work from a browser?

Comment: yes work.
but i don't understand how to get item from this url : http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730

Comment: I do not see that webpage calling any API when the page is loading. Is there a documentation available for this?

Comment: Here is [the documentation](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetAssetClassInfo) for the command you use. Maybe it is of help for you.